# JSON - no Response data, using Retrofit and Gson

Tags: json, android-recyclerview, gson, android

Issue: Request is being done(hits are increasing) but there is no Response.
What I did so far:
 - I rechecked all the namings and type
 - Went through all similar StackOverflow questions

Log:

```
Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Json data:

```
{
"total": 1,
"error": "",
"train": [
{
  "travel_time": "21:15",
  "from": {
    "name": "GORAKHPUR",
    "code": "GKP"
  },
  "number": "12591",
  "src_departure_time": "06:35",
  "to": {
    "name": "NAGPUR",
    "code": "NGP"
  },
  "classes": [
    {
      "available": "N",
      "class-code": "2S"
    },
    {
      "available": "Y",
      "class-code": "3A"
    },
    {
      "available": "N",
      "class-code": "CC"
    },
    {
      "available": "N",
      "class-code": "FC"
    },
    {
      "available": "N",
      "class-code": "1A"
    },
    {
      "available": "Y",
      "class-code": "SL"
    },
    {
      "available": "N",
      "class-code": "3E"
    },
    {
      "available": "Y",
      "class-code": "2A"
    }
  ],
  "days": [
    {
      "runs": "N",
      "day-code": "MON"
    },
    {
      "runs": "N",
      "day-code": "TUE"
    },
    {
      "runs": "N",
      "day-code": "WED"
    },
    {
      "runs": "N",
      "day-code": "THU"
    },
    {
      "runs": "N",
      "day-code": "FRI"
    },
    {
      "runs": "Y",
      "day-code": "SAT"
    },
    {
      "runs": "N",
      "day-code": "SUN"
    }
  ],
  "no": 1,
  "name": "GKP-SBC EXP",
  "dest_arrival_time": "03:50"
}
],
"response_code": 200
}
```

TrainFromToResponse.java:

```
 package com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class TrainFromToResponse {

private int total;
private String error;
private List<Train> train = new ArrayList<Train>();
private int response_code;


/**
 *
 * @return
 * The train
 */
public List<Train> getTrain() {
    return train;
}

/**
 *
 * @param train
 * The train
 */
public void setTrain(List<Train> train) {
    this.train = train;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The responseCode
 */
public int getResponseCode() {
    return response_code;
}

/**
 *
 * @param responseCode
 * The response_code
 */
public void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
    this.response_code = responseCode;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The total
 */
public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

/**
 *
 * @param total
 * The total
 */
public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The error
 */
public String getError() {
    return error;
}

/**
 *
 * @param error
 * The error
 */
public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}
}
```

Train.java:

```
package com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Train {

private List<Days> days = new ArrayList<Days>();
private int no;
private String number;
private String dest_arrival_time;
private To to;
private From from;
private List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
private String name;
private String src_departure_time;
private String travel_time;


/**
 *
 * @return
 * The days
 */
public List<Days> getDays() {
    return days;
}

/**
 *
 * @param days
 * The days
 */
public void setDays(List<Days> days) {
    this.days = days;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The no
 */
public int getNo() {
    return no;
}

/**
 *
 * @param no
 * The no
 */
public void setNo(int no) {
    this.no = no;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The number
 */
public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

/**
 *
 * @param number
 * The number
 */
public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The destArrivalTime
 */
public String getDestArrivalTime() {
    return dest_arrival_time;
}

/**
 *
 * @param destArrivalTime
 * The dest_arrival_time
 */
public void setDestArrivalTime(String destArrivalTime) {
    this.dest_arrival_time = destArrivalTime;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The to
 */
public To getTo() {
    return to;
}

/**
 *
 * @param to
 * The to
 */
public void setTo(To to) {
    this.to = to;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The from
 */
public From getFrom() {
    return from;
}

/**
 *
 * @param from
 * The from
 */
public void setFrom(From from) {
    this.from = from;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The classes
 */
public List<Class> getClasses() {
    return classes;
}

/**
 *
 * @param classes
 * The classes
 */
public void setClasses(List<Class> classes) {
    this.classes = classes;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The srcDepartureTime
 */
public String getSrcDepartureTime() {
    return src_departure_time;
}

/**
 *
 * @param srcDepartureTime
 * The src_departure_time
 */
public void setSrcDepartureTime(String srcDepartureTime) {
    this.src_departure_time = srcDepartureTime;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The travelTime
 */
public String getTravelTime() {
    return travel_time;
}

/**
 *
 * @param travelTime
 * The travel_time
 */
public void setTravelTime(String travelTime) {
    this.travel_time = travelTime;
}
}
```

From.java:

```
package com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class From {

private String code;
private String name;


/**
 *
 * @return
 * The code
 */
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

/**
 *
 * @param code
 * The code
 */
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

To.java:

```
package com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class To {

private String code;
private String name;

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The code
 */
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

/**
 *
 * @param code
 * The code
 */
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Classes:

```
package com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Classes {

private String available;
@SerializedName("class-code")
private String classCode;


/**
 *
 * @return
 * The available
 */
public String getAvailable() {
    return available;
}

/**
 *
 * @param available
 * The available
 */
public void setAvailable(String available) {
    this.available = available;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The classCode
 */
public String getClassCode() {
    return classCode;
}

/**
 *
 * @param classCode
 * The class-code
 */
public void setClassCode(String classCode) {
    this.classCode = classCode;
}
}
```

Days:

```
package com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Days {

private String runs;
@SerializedName("day-code")
private String dayCode;


/**
 *
 * @return
 * The runs
 */
public String getRuns() {
    return runs;
}

/**
 *
 * @param runs
 * The runs
 */
public void setRuns(String runs) {
    this.runs = runs;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The dayCode
 */
public String getDayCode() {
    return dayCode;
}

/**
 *
 * @param dayCode
 * The day-code
 */
public void setDayCode(String dayCode) {
    this.dayCode = dayCode;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referenced `java.lang.Class` instead of `com.vyshnav.trainfromto.model.Classes` on this line:

```
private List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Comment: what am I supposed to do?

Comment: 2 days for a careless mistake!! Tnx Jake.. Getting in love with Stack now..

Answer (score 0):

As Jake mentioned, I had mistyped 'Classes' as 'Class'.